Excel Column Chart: Overlap 2 series and bring series 1 bars and x-axis to front
The following code creates a clustered column chart with 2 series.
How do you build it to have

Series 1 on top of Series 2

and

Series 1 categories as the x-axis?

Using
With .SeriesCollection(1)
    .AxisGroup = 2
End With

brings the bars of Series 1 to the front.
But the x-axis is not affected, it's still the Series 2 x-axis.
How do you bring the Series 1 x-axis to the front as well?
Option Explicit

Sub CreateChartClustCol2Series_01_()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim objChart As ChartObject
  Dim myDataRange As Range
  Dim myDataRange2a As Range
  Dim myDataRange2b As Range
  Dim myChtRange As Range
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  With ws
  On Error Resume Next
    Set myDataRange = Application.InputBox _
        (Title:="Series 1 Cat Row + Val Row", Prompt:="", Type:=8)
    Set myDataRange2a = Application.InputBox _
        (Title:="Series 2 Cat Row", Prompt:="", Type:=8)
    Set myDataRange2b = Application.InputBox _
       (Title:="Series 2 Val Row", Prompt:="", Type:=8)
    Set myChtRange = Application.InputBox _
        (Title:="Chart Area", Prompt:="", Type:=8)
    Set objChart = .ChartObjects.Add( _
        Left:=myChtRange.Left, Top:=myChtRange.Top, _
        Width:=myChtRange.Width, Height:=myChtRange.Height)
    With objChart.Chart
        .SetSourceData Source:=myDataRange
        With .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .XValues = myDataRange2a  ' Category
            .Values = myDataRange2b   ' Value
        End With
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
            .AxisGroup = 2
        End With
        With .SeriesCollection(2)
            .ChartType = xlColumnClustered
'            .AxisGroup = 2
        End With
        .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 50
        .HasLegend = False
        .HasTitle = False
        With .ChartArea
            .AutoScaleFont = False
        End With
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)
        ' X-Axis Series 1
        .HasAxis(xlCategory) = True
            With .Axes(xlCategory)
                .Format.Line.Visible = True
                .MajorTickMark = xlNone
                .TickLabelPosition = xlLow
                .TickLabels.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                .TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
            End With
        ' Y-Axis Series 1
        .HasAxis(xlValue) = True
            With .Axes(xlValue)
                .Format.Line.Visible = True
                .Format.Fill.Visible = False
                .MaximumScale = 1000
                .MinimumScale = -1000
                .MajorUnit = 250
                .MinorUnit = 50
                .CrossesAt = 0
                .MajorTickMark = xlInside
                .MinorTickMark = xlNone
                .TickLabelPosition = xlNone
            End With
        ' X-Axis Series 2
        .HasAxis(xlCategory, xlSecondary) = False
            With .Axes(xlCategory, xlSecondary)
                .Format.Line.Visible = True
                .MajorTickMark = xlNone
                .TickLabelPosition = xlLow
                .TickLabels.Font.Name = "Calibri"
                .TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
            End With
        ' Y-Axis Series 2
        .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
            With .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary)
                .Format.Line.Visible = False
                .MaximumScale = 1000
                .MinimumScale = -1000
                .CrossesAt = 0
                .TickLabelPosition = xlNone
            End With
    End With
  On Error GoTo 0
  End With
  If myDataRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If myDataRange2a Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If myDataRange2b Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
  If myChtRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
End Sub



Both series are plotted with the same values, resulting in bars of the same height. The only difference between the first and third series is the fill color, which can be easily changed with code.

There's a fundamental misunderstanding of charts here. There are 2 vertical axes and only 1 horizontal axis (for normal orientation charts). For each series, you can specify whether it is plotted against the primary or secondary vertical axis, but they're all plotted against the single horizontal axis.
When you update the XValues, you're not updating them for just the second series, you're updating them for all series. If you want the XValues to remain as set for the first series, then just remove the line of code that updates the XValues, so that they remain as per for the initially defined values.
